# Integers.parseint( on scanner input ), also i want to make limits so user can only input number in range from 0 to 100

Tags: java, parsing, integer, java.util.scanner

Hello guys im having little problem here, 
Firstly i want to parse string which comes from scanner into int, so i can later use it IF statement. 
Code looks like this

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner numbers = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("Current list is " + list);
        System.out.println("Add more? (y/n)");

        if (numbers.next().startsWith("y")) 
        {
            if(Integer.parseInt(numbers)> 0 && Integer.parseInt(numbers) < 101)
            {// i get error on above line, and im kinda lost here


                System.out.println("Enter : ");
                list.add(numbers.next());
            }
        }
        else
        {            
            break;                
        }           
    }while (true);
```

Any help appreciated, hopefully i made my self clear and my problem too

Edit:

```
        do {

        System.out.println("Current list is " + list);
        System.out.println("Add more? (y/n)");

        if (numbers.next().startsWith("y")) 
        {                               
            System.out.print("Enter: "); 
            System.out.flush();                
            final int n = Integer.parseInt(numbers.next());
            if (n > 0 && n < 101) 
            {
                list.add(n);
                // this is where i get the error.

                //no suitable method found for add(int)
                // method java.util.List.add(int,java.lang.String) is not applicable
                // (actual and formal arguments lists differ in length)
                // method java.util.List.add(java.lang.String) is not applicable
                // (actual argument int cannot be converted to java.lang.String 
                // by method invocation conversion).

                // end of log
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Number you have entered exceeds raange between 0-100");
            } 
        }
        else
        {            
            break;                
        }           
    }while (true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you wanted to write

```
System.out.print("Enter: "); System.out.flush();
final int n = Integer.parseInt(numbers.next());
if (n > 0 && n < 101) list.add(n);
```

`java.util.Scanner` also contains the method `nextInt`, which obviates the need for `Integer.parseInt`. You can just say `numbers.nextInt()`.

You also need to change your list declaration from `List<String>` to `List<Integer>`.

Comment: You'll need to post your exact code and also post the exact error stacktrace.

Comment: Thank you  for your response Marko, Well the problem is with the list.add(n) this is where it throws error, when i change it to list.add(numbers.next()) it works but makes me type twice the same number.

error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.util.List.add
 at assess1grade.GradeCalculator.readGrade(GradeCalculator.java:44)

Comment: You should post this stuff by editing your question and formatting it properly. I don't entirely get that exception. Post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: java can not autocast an int to a String it can autobox an int to an Integer which can be converted to a String but it does not do this in the add line. 
You have got 2 possibe fixxes:

(1) change your list to List<Integer> 
 so when calling list.add(n) the int n will be autoboxed to an  
 Integer and be added
(2) change the line list.add(n) to list.add(""+n)
 this can java handle to create a String

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse non-integer (String) to integer which throws `NumberFormatException` in cases where input is non-integer.

```
int n=0;

try
{
n = Integer.parseInt(numbers.next());
}catch(Exception e)
{
}

if(n > 0 && n<101)
{
//your logic
}
```